# Variable not updating on UI

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Currently i have a user inputting a new name into an input field, and saving that name into "newTitle"
However, when pressing "save" and firing the edittitle() function - it updates the values, console.logs correctly, however the UI element does not update until i manually refresh the page.

```
let newTitle = 'my new title'

async function editTitle() {
   array[0].title = newTitle
   array = array
}

<h1> array[0].title </h1>
```

Im struggling with the reactivity parts of sveltekit Expecially within Arrays.

Tried using the Reactive variables($:) to no success

A post online said about using array = array; but that dosn't seem to be working either

Comment: Please provide a full example showing the problem, because that code would work as expected (if curly braces are added in the `h1`).